# Highcharts Line - When Y axis min is set to 0, connecting line isn't shown for consecutive 0 values

Tags: highcharts

For a line chart with consecutive 0 values, the 0 points are not connected if the Y axis "min" value is set to 0. Check out the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ke7RM/

There appears to be a clipPath in the SVG that is clipping this line, but I can't find a way to alter that path through the Highcharts API.

```
<clipPath id="highcharts-1"><rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="332" height="292"></rect></clipPath>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Looks like this has been fixed in the latest version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is known bug, reported to our developers here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1687

You can try to set min value or threshold:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.threshold
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min